# C - X11 API: Custom Control Redraw Issue

Tags: c, gcc, window, controls, x11

I am working on a project in the X11 API, and I have a Window based custom control consistently rendering. But for some reason, when I re-size the window, the control does not redraw unless I interact with the control directly, or move the entire main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I just needed to add the Structure Notify Mask to my custom window input.

```
XSelectInput(display, CustomWindow, StructureNotifyMask);
```